# Overriding method in secondary class

Tags: android

I have a super-class called *MainActivity* and a secondary class called *Insert*. 
The two class are defined as the code below.The *Insert* class  extends the *MainActivity* class.
In the two class I have the onStop() method, and in the *Insert* class I have @Override. The problem is that when onStop is executed in the *Insert* class, also the onStop method of *MainActivity* is called. Why? How can I do?
Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onStop() {
        //some code
        super.onStop();
    }
}


public class Insert extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        //some code
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `super.onStop()` in `Insert` overriden method?

Comment: @Google yes! in both method of the two class. I put it at the end of the method (before the closing parentesis} )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onStop is the default method provided by activity lifecycle. You can have your custom method name say onMyStop() and call that method from Insert class's onStop using super.onMyStop()

Answer (score 0):

The reason is calling `super.onStop()` in `Insert` overriden method. But calling `super.onStop` is mandatory. To fix it, you can create another method like `doOnStop` in `MainActivity`, call it inside `onStop` of `MainActivity` and override in `Insert` without calling `super.doOnStop`.

Here is code sampe:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        doOnStop();
        //some code
    }

    public void doOnStop() {

    }
}


public class Insert extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    public void doOnStop() {
        //some code
    }
}
```